# Substituir document.xml de docx - Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

É possível substituir o document.xml do xml do DOCX original?

Estou trabalhando em um sistema de faz upload de um arquivo em DOC, como byte para um campo BLOB em um banco em  Oracle.
Depois o sistema faz a substituição de alguns texto marcados com [[texto]], utilizando o xml.
Como resultado deste processo, gera um DOC com o texto substituídos.

Foi solicitado para o mesmo fazer o processo com DOCX, que pelo que entendi em um conjunto de xml, entre ele o documento.xml.

Consegui extrair o xml de texto do DOCX, fazer a substituições do campos variáveis, mas quando mando para o fontend ele gera o arquivo, mas não consigo abrir.

Extração de document.xml do DOCX

```
            XWPFDocument docx;
            try {
                docx = new XWPFDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(draft));
                XmlObject documentXmlObject = docx.getDocument();
                doc = convertStringToXMLDocument(documentXmlObject.toString());
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                throw new BusinessException("", e);
            }
```

convertStringToXMLDocument

```
   private static Document convertStringToXMLDocument(String xmlString) 
    {
        //Parser that produces DOM object trees from XML content
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         
        //API to obtain DOM Document instance
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;
        try
        {
            //Create DocumentBuilder with default configuration
            builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
             
            //Parse the content to Document object
            Document doc = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));
            return doc;
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Erro quando eu envio o xml esta extração para o front ( Texto da Mensagem: O Word encontrou conteúdo ilegível no arquivo. Deseja recuperar o conteúdo?):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Clico em sim, e o mesmo dá outro erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Está utilizando a biblioteca Apache POI? Qual import está utilizando para o Document? se estiver utilizando o mesmo pacote para gravar o arquivo editado em DOC e em DOCX, pode ser que você esteja gravando um arquivo doc com a extensão docx.

Comment: Está utilizando a biblioteca Apache POI? - Sim

Comment: Qual import está utilizando para o Document? - getByte do front

Comment: Pelo que li não irei conseguir utilizar a mesmo processo para DOC e DOCX.

Comment: Isto mesmo você terá que utilizar org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument para (.doc)  ou um tipo org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument para (.docx). Se não cuidar em todo o processo, pode obter este erro da tela.

Comment: Isso que eu li mesmo.... vou ter que ir por este caminho.

Answer (score 0):

A biblioteca do Apache POI é dividida em duas partes

Para arquivos **.doc** utilizar:

```
org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument
```

Para arquivos **.docx** utilizar:

```
org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument
```

Caso tente abrir um arquivo **.doc** com biblioteca `org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument` ou caso tente abrir um arquivo **.docx** com a biblioteca `org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument` poderá receber os erros citados na pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

obrigado pela resposta.

Um colega de trabalho resolveu o problema, segue código abaixo:

```
    public static byte[] processorDocx(Document doc) {
    XWPFDocument mergedDocuments = new XWPFDocument();
    CTDocument1 mergedCTDocument = mergedDocuments.getDocument();
    mergedCTDocument.unsetBody();  // to remove blank first page in merged document
    String xmlDoc = convertDocumentToString(doc);
    CTDocument1 srcCTDocument;
    try {
        srcCTDocument = CTDocument1.Factory.parse(xmlDoc);
        if (srcCTDocument != null) {
            CTBody srcCTBody = srcCTDocument.getBody();
            if (srcCTBody != null) {
                CTBody mergedCTBody = mergedCTDocument.addNewBody();
                mergedCTBody.set(srcCTBody);
            }
        }
          ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            try {
                mergedDocuments.write(out);
                out.close();
                mergedDocuments.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
          
            byte[] xwpfDocumentBytes = out.toByteArray();
            
            return xwpfDocumentBytes;  
          
    } catch (XmlException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }     
        
    return null;
}
```